# Get a non-id form with HTML-UNIT C#

Tags: c#, htmlunit

So I've got a HtmlPage with 2 forms in it, not one of those have Id to get.

I've tried to get them by getting the last child on the body (which is the form I need to get), I've been trying to receive it on a HTMLFORM element, but no luck. Any ideas?

Edit:
I'm adding the part of the code you can see :(

```
                <table width="650" bordercolor="#cccccc" bgcolor="white" border="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <font size="1">ACCION </font>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <font size="1">ESTADO </font>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <font size="1">DESCRIPCION </font>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <font size="1">CANTIDAD </font>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <form action="le_02pre_deim_anticipada.asp?submit=AA" method="post"></form>
                        <input name="cod_estado" type="hidden" value="100">
                        <input name="descrip" type="hidden" value="100">
                        <input name="buzon" type="hidden" value="B1_">
                        <input name="filtro_fecha" type="hidden" value="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" align="CENTER">
                                <input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" value="SELECCIONAR"></td>
                            <td width="10%" align="CENTER">
                                <font size="2">100</font>
                            </td>
                            <td width="60%">
                                <font size="2">
                                    Informadas en espera de la presentación en Bancos
                                </font>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="CENTER">
                                <font size="2">233</font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <form action="le_02pre_deim_anticipada.asp?submit=AA" method="post"></form>
                        <input name="cod_estado" type="hidden" value="200">
                        <input name="descrip" type="hidden" value="200">
                        <input name="buzon" type="hidden" value="B2_">
                        <input name="filtro_fecha" type="hidden" value="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" align="CENTER" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                                <input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" value="SELECCIONAR"></td>
                            <td width="10%" align="CENTER" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                                <font size="2">200</font>
                            </td>
                            <td width="60%" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                                <font size="2">
                                    Presentadas en entidades recaudadoras en espera de la Solicitud de Levante
                                </font>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="CENTER" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                                <font size="2">194</font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

So I need to send this values through post.

```
<input name="cod_estado" type="hidden" value="200">
<input name="descrip" type="hidden" value="200">
<input name="buzon" type="hidden" value="B2_">
<input name="filtro_fecha" type="hidden" value="1">
```

I'm receiving the body on:

```
HtmlBody body0 = (HtmlBody)P0.Body;
```

Comment: If you are wondering.. Yes, is the first time I use this HTMLUNIT thing, and yes, I have to use that one. :( thanks.

Comment: Show us your code. What do you mean by 'but no luck'? Has any of the `input` elements in the for an id? If yes you can search for this and use `getParent()` to get the form.

Comment: Maybe you can add the HTML-code to your question.

Comment: Sure, let me get the code up...

Comment: The P0 has 5 different frames, the one that shows the body is:
<frame name="frame_02" src="cm_02contenido.asp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" target="frame_02"> and inside that one is the table I posted above.

Comment: I see I can execute something on js instead of sending the POST request cause is more complicated that way. I'm going to try that first.

Answer (score 0):

### I solved it :D

I just wanted to let you know how I solved this issue.
Not one element on the page has ID, but you can use the position of some markers to navigate it.

```
HtmlForm f02Submit = PageDecla.Forms[1];
HtmlSubmitInput SubM02 = (HtmlSubmitInput)PageDecla.GetElementsByName("SUBMIT")[1];
f02Submit.AppendChild(SubM02);
var count = f02Submit.ChildElementCount;
SubM02 = (HtmlSubmitInput)f02Submit.ChildNodes[count-1];
PaginaDecla = (HtmlPage)SubM02.Click();
f02Submit = null;
SubM02 = null;
int f = 0, hfImp = 0;
f = PaginaDecla.Forms.Count;


for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
{
    var form = PageDecla.Forms[i];
    hfImp = form.ChildElementCount;
    SubM02 = (HtmlSubmitInput)PageDecla.GetElementsByName("SUBMIT")[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < hfImp; j++)
    {                    
        var hfI = (HtmlHiddenInput)form.ChildNodes[j];
        var nameHF = hfI.NameAttribute;
        var val = hfI.ValueAttribute;
        if ((val == cod_int) && (nameHF == name))
        {
            form.AppendChild(SubM02);
            hfImp = form.ChildElementCount;
            var btn = (HtmlSubmitInput)form.ChildNodes[hfImp-1];
            PageDecla = (HtmlPage)btn.Click();
            j = hfImp;
            i = f;
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks for those who tried, I know I did not provide that much information.